# How to prevent mousedown event in focusout event?

Tags: jquery, hide, show, mousedown, focusout

I am a beginner with jQuery and I added a jQuery in order to keep certain div elements in view and other div elements hidden when the focus of the button is gone (click outside the element). However, when you click down on the button, you see the "shown" elements. How do I prevent this from happening? I tried a `.mousedown` `return default` action, but no luck.

```
$(".table-btn").focusout(function() {
            $("#pricelist0").show();
            $("#pricelist1, #pricelist2").hide();
    })
```

**Edit:**
I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zuje1md0/25) to make the problem more visible, so when you click down on the other button, pricelist0 appears.

**Extra:**
With the given answer, and to be able to not loose the focus of the button when certain elements are clicked, you can additionally add the following code. Where any elements are the elements where you would like to keep the button be focused.

```
var lastFocus;
    $("any element").mousedown(function(e) {
    return false;
    });    
    $(".table-btn").blur(function() {
        lastFocus = this;
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click `#pricelist1` or `#pricelist2` it triggers `focusout` for the other button, that's why `#pricelist0` was shown.

Try this;

```
$(document).on("click", ":not(.table-btn)", function(e){
    if(e.target !== this)
        return;

    $("#pricelist0").show();
    $("#pricelist1, #pricelist2").hide();
});
$("#1").click(function(){
    $("#pricelist1").show();
    $("#pricelist2, #pricelist0").hide();
});
$("#2").click(function(e){
    $("#pricelist2").show();
    $("#pricelist1, #pricelist0").hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but it's not working, when you click in the "text area" `#pricelist0` is not showing, only when you click within the div of the pricelist.

I understand now the error, but shouldn't a `click` event being implemented in the `focusout` event? Why is the `focusout` event not applicable here?

Comment: @Demian checkout the edit. `focusout` is not working here because it's not triggered when you hold the mouse down.

Comment: Yes thank you this does it, I added the above extra code in order to not loose the focus of the button for various elements.